# Python 3 Building an array of bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, arrays

I need to build a tcp frame with raw binary data, but all examples and tutorials I've found talking about bytes always involve conversion from a string, and that's not what I need.

In short, I need to build just an array of bytes:

`0xA2 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04`

Please note that I come from C/C++ world.

I've tried this:

```
frame = b""
frame += bytes( int('0xA2',16) )
frame += bytes( int('0x01',16) )
frame += bytes( int('0x02',16) )
frame += bytes( int('0x03',16) )
frame += bytes( int('0x04',16) )
```

Then, throw this frame variable to send method of socket, but not working as expected as frame doesn't contain what I want...

I know this is a very basic question about Python, so if you could point me in the right direction...

Comment: The problem with the above code is that `bytes` behaves very differently if given an integer instead of a list.  You should be using `frame += bytes( [ int('0xa2',16) ] )`.

Comment: I know that you want(ed) to do this dynamically, but what is completely unclear is this: where do the input bytes come from? You read hex notation from a text file? You write each byte down in the source code? You have them in an bytearray which you got from reading binary from stdin?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray):

```
>>> frame = bytearray()
>>> frame.append(0xA2)
>>> frame.append(0x01)
>>> frame.append(0x02)
>>> frame.append(0x03)
>>> frame.append(0x04)
>>> frame
bytearray(b'\xa2\x01\x02\x03\x04')
```

or, using your code but fixing the errors:

```
frame = b""
frame += b'\xA2' 
frame += b'\x01' 
frame += b'\x02' 
frame += b'\x03'
frame += b'\x04'
```

Comment: you added the tag bytearray to the question when the answer may not use it as a solution.

Comment: @clinisbut It's still related -- in the general sense, you're using a byte array (the concept) even if you're not using the `bytearray` type. Either of the two methods in my answer should solve your problem.

Comment: you can replace `bytearray`with `bytes` and get roughly the same result. a `bytearray` is a mutable type though, so it may be more useful than a `bytes` for constructing your frames.

Comment: @agf: that's what you do. i was just telling clinisbut the difference between `bytearray`and `bytes`. but now i may need to explain the difference between a mutable and an immutable type.

Answer (score 19):

what about simply constructing your frame from a standard list ?

```
frame = bytes([0xA2,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04])
```

the `bytes()` constructor can build a byte frame from an iterable containing `int` values. an iterable is anything which implements the iterator protocol: an list, an iterator, an iterable object like what is returned by `range()`...

Answer (score 9):

```
frame = b'\xa2\x01\x02\x03\x04'
```

wasn't mentionned till now...

Comment: but I need to build the frame dynamically

Comment: this syntax for building an array of bytes works the same as for a string type: you can use `+` or other similar operators to build your byte array dynamically.

Answer (score 7):

agf's bytearray solution is workable, but if you find yourself needing to build up more complicated packets using datatypes other than bytes, you can try `struct.pack()`. http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/struct.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to getting an array (list) of bytes:

I found that you needed to convert the Int to a byte first, before passing it to the bytes():

```
bytes(int('0xA2', 16).to_bytes(1, "big"))
```

Then create a list from the bytes:

```
list(frame)
```

So your code should look like:

```
frame = b""
frame += bytes(int('0xA2', 16).to_bytes(1, "big"))
frame += bytes(int('0x01', 16).to_bytes(1, "big"))
frame += bytes(int('0x02', 16).to_bytes(1, "big"))
frame += bytes(int('0x03', 16).to_bytes(1, "big"))
frame += bytes(int('0x04', 16).to_bytes(1, "big"))
bytesList = list(frame)
```

The question was for an array (list) of bytes. You accepted an answer that doesn't tell how to get a list so I'm not sure if this is actually what you needed.