# How to create a bytearray of fixed bytes?

Tags: python

I am doing AES encryption and want to use a static key for it.

In C I would do -

unsigned char key[16] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

How do I do that in python?

Also if I want to look at the class/code for the AES class from Crypto.cipher where do I find it?

I am using python2.7

Comment: You might look at this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7556308/5870826)

Comment: Regarding your second question, [here's PyCrypto source on Github](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto)

Comment: `key = bytearray(16)`

Comment: might consider `numpy` as well. `key = numpy.empty([16], dtype=uint8)`

Answer (score 0):

A `bytearray` object has a constructor that takes a *source* parameter. If the source is a string, you have to worry about character encodings, etc. But if the source is an *iterable*, it will iterate over the values, which must be `0 <= x < 256` for obvious reasons, and compose the starting bytearray from that.

Thus, you could do something like:

```
key = bytearray([0] * 16)    # sixteen NULs
```

or

```
key = bytearray([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 0, 0, 0])
```

or whatever.