# Does Perl 6 have an equivalent to Python's bytearray method?

Tags: python, encoding, raku

I can't find `bytearray` method or similar in Raku [doc](https://docs.raku.org) as in Python. In Python, the [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=bytearray#bytearray) defined as this:

```
class bytearray([source[, encoding[, errors]]])
```

> Return a new array of bytes. The bytearray class is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256. It has most of the usual methods of mutable sequences, described in Mutable Sequence Types, as well as most methods that the str type has, see String Methods.

Does Raku should provide this method or some module?

Comment: Note there is [`CArray[int8]`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall#index-entry-CArray) in the [`NativeCall`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/nativecall) module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

brian d foy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555689/python-3-building-an-array-of-bytes) is essentially correct. You can pretty much translate [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555689/python-3-building-an-array-of-bytes) into Perl6

```
 my $frame = Buf.new; 
 $frame.append(0xA2); 
 $frame.append(0x01); 
 say $frame; # OUTPUT: «Buf:0x<a2 01>␤»
```

However, the declaration is not the same:

```
bu = bytearray( 'þor', encoding='utf8',errors='replace')
```

in Python would be equivalent to this in Perl 6

```
my $bú =  Buf.new('þor'.encode('utf-8')); 
say $bú; # OUTPUT: «Buf:0x<c3 be 6f 72>␤»
```

And to use something equivalent to the error transformation, the approach is different due to the way Perl 6 approaches Unicode normalization; you would probably have to use [`UTF8 Clean 8`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/unicode#index-entry-UTF8-C8) encoding.

For most uses, however, I guess `Buf`, as indicated by brian d foy, is correct.

Answer (score 10):

I think you're looking for [Buf](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Buf) - a mutable sequence of (usually unsigned) integers. Opening a file with `:bin` returns a `Buf`.

Comment: Any Perl 5 equivalent of `Buf` or of Python 2 `bytearray` / Python 3 `bytes`?  (By the way, congrats in advance on 100K rep!)

Comment: You can read input in Perl 5 with ':raw'. You get an octet stream. Things such as JSON parser want the UTF-8 octets, for instance. Beyond that it probably deserves its own question.